# Не работает rstudio

Tags: rstudio

Со вчерашнего дня rstudio стал открываться вот так вот:
[image]
Просто белый экран, не зависает, но верхнее меня не активно. То есть эффект ховера есть, но от нажатия никакого эффекта. Переустановка не помогла. В пути к файлам русских символов нет. 
Что делать и где искать решение проблемы? Даже не знаю почему так.

Answer (score 1):

1. Во-первых проверься на вирусы. Чито на всякий случай.
2. Потом удали саму апликуху
3. Потом поиском найди все файлы которые относятся к р-студио и удали их так же. (в програм файлс и в аппДата)
4. Потом удали все папки/ключи из реестра которые относятся к р-студио
5. И установи заново. Желательно -- с нового инсталятора. :)

Comment: Что такое апликуха? Сорре, я с луны

Comment: программа=апликуха=рстудио(в даном контексте)

Comment: Не помогло:( Я заглянул в деспетчер задач. Вот, каждый раз когда я запускаю рстудио там появляется просто огромное количество процессов Git for Windows

Comment: если эти пункты не помогли -- скорей всего что-то с осью. (виндой). Ну... Или же ты неправильно сделал написанное.