# RStudio "Прекращена работа..."

Tags: rstudio

`RStudio` перестала запускаться и сообщает:

```
Прекращена работа программы... Windows осуществляет поиск способа устранения...
```

Переустановка не помогла.

Установлена `Win7 x64 SP1`.
Антивирус отключаю.
Названия папок на англ.
P.S. RStudio путь к R видит...

Comment: Попробуйте правую кнопку мыши и запустить от администратора. Антивира нет - плохо. Потом попробуйте в режиме совместимости. Если не получится - нужно разбираться с системой.

Comment: Пожалуйста) - И все-таки - работал и перестал - значит, либо в нем изменения, не дающие запуск в Вашей системе, либо что изменилось в Вашей системе - например, включили защиту или еще что - надо бы восттановить, что предшествовало проблеме. И второе - а почему бы не перейти на 10?  Все одно придется - многое и многое не сможет работать в 7 из обновленных и современных программ.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не работает rstudio](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/659535/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-rstudio)